# WCF DataContract Serializer in combination with Expression Body Property

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization

Those two classes should be equivalent:

**class1.cs**

```
[DataContract]
public class MyClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public int? UserId { get; set; }

    public bool IsAdmin
    {
        get { return UserId == null; }
    }
}
```

Resharper transformed this with expression body:

**class2.cs**

```
[DataContract]
public class MyClass
{   
    [DataMember]
    public int? UserId { get; set; }

    public bool IsAdmin => UserId == null;
}
```

When i try to serialize *class2.cs* it throws:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException: No set method for property 'IsAdmin' in type 'MyClass'.

But when i try to serialize *class1.cs* with WCF it works as expected.

What is the difference here?

Comment: `IsAdmin` shouldn't be throwing a problem with `DataContract` since it's not marked by `DataMember`.   If you mark `IsAdmin` with `[DataMember]` in `class1` I'd expect you to get the same error message, as there is no setter in `class1`.  .